# Calling buttons in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, button

I'm using objective C in Xcode to create a project. I am having problems calling a button function within another button function. Could someone help me please!?

Comment: Show the code you're using; if you have none that's likely the problem.

Comment: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

> // First Button's Touch Event :-

-(IBAction)firstButtonDidClicked:(UIButton *)sender {

```
[self  secondButtonDidClicked:sender];
```

}

> //Second Button's Touch Event :-

-(IBAction)secondButtonDidClicked:(UIButton *)sender {

```
//do some work
```

}

Comment: Would you have any idea on how to display text(which im getting from a .txt file) using UIScrollView. Is it just like text view? Because im stuck with how to change this: _wordDefBox.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",_wordDefBox.text, lines[0]];              so that it  uses scrollView instead of textView?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call IBAction methods directly like other methods, but you can invoke IBAction methods in following way:

```
[button sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Would you have any idea on how to display text(which im getting from a .txt file) using UIScrollView. Is it just like text view? Because im stuck with how to change this: _wordDefBox.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",_wordDefBox.text, lines[0]];              so that it  uses scrollView instead of textView?

Comment: No, you can not directly display text(write text) into UIScrollView, and UITextView is not same as UIScrollView, the only common feature they both provide is scrolling when their connect size is larger then its frame size. But if you still need to use UIScrollView then you need to place your controls inside UIScrollView.